# how to create a RTSP Server using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I created RTSP server using following command. (proxy rtsp)

```
./test-launch " rtspsrc location=rtsp://[url] protocols=4 ! rtph264depay ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt= 9"
```

It work fine.
But RTSP server URL can only be set rtsp://localhost:8554/test.

I want to configure port and path in URL.test-launch
How to set port and URL?

Comment: It is a test application. IT doesn't care about features. You need to modify - or better write your own application.

Comment: Thx. You mean Gstreamer command can't create RTSP server?

Comment: `GstRtspServer` is a library. You can use to create your own things. Check https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server for documentation and examples.